# IF a URL contains a date in PHP

Tags: php

I have a web site to analyze Instagram account and create report, and there's a function to display report for a particular dates range.

If I have date selected, then URL become `${base_url}/${date_start}/${date_end}` , i.e.:
https://www.example.com/report/account-name/2020-02-01/2020-03-31

I want show historical data only to my premium users, so I need a way to check if URLs contain the value

```
/${date_start}/${date_end}
```

If "YES", then I'll show a notice to invite users to upgrade their plan.

I only miss the code to check IF URL contain `/${date_start}/${date_end}`

How to do that?

ps: dates is always wrotten like YYYY-MM-DD , so this should make thing easier, I suppose.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: define each param in your router, then use DateTime::createFromFormat on each to validate, both in the expected format and date_end < date_start etc if your not using a router you can use parse_url from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and explode by / etc to get the params your after

Answer (score 1):

that is a regular expression you are looking for

```
if (preg_match('/\/\d\d\d\d-[01]?\d-[0-3]?\d\/\d\d\d\d-[01]?\d-[0-3]?\d/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    echo 'dates found';
} else {
    echo 'dates not found';
}
```

Comment: @GeronimoFantusio not really, it would also match `/0000-0-0/0000-0-0`, or `/9999-19-39/9999-19-39` both are not valid dates

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I know, but I don't care about this, as is impossible my script display invalid dates.